# Oracle SQL splitting a string field on character count and append a letter at the end

Tags: sql, string, oracle, split, append

I am facing a situation where I have a Oracle database table String field where I want to append a letters at beggining and at end with size max length 5.

```
eg- The  original string = AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD
out put string =EAAAAAFEBBBBDFECCCCCFEDDDDDF
```

Here after character size of 5 is identified E is appended at the beginning and F at the end. how can I achieve this using oracle sql select query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your output string has a typo and that it should be  `'EAAAAAFEBBBBBFECCCCCFEDDDDDF'`, this could be a way:

```
SELECT sys_connect_by_path( substr(x, 1 + (level-1)*5, 5) || 'F', 'E')
  FROM (select 'AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD' x from dual) text
where connect_by_isleaf = 1  
CONNECT BY level * 5 <= length(x)
```

How it works:
the `CONNECT BY` impements recursion and the condition `level * 5 <= length(x)` makes it stop when level (the number of iteration) is big enough to comsume all the string.
With this string, you have 4 groups of 5 chcracters each, so you get 4 iterations:

```
SQL> select level
  2    FROM (select 'AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD' x from dual) text
  3  CONNECT BY level * 5 <= length(x);

     LEVEL
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
```

Once you have recursion, at each iteration you need to get the nth group of characters:

```
SQL> select level, substr(x, 1 + (level-1)*5, 5)
  2    FROM (select 'AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD' x from dual) text
  3  CONNECT BY level * 5 <= length(x);

     LEVEL SUBSTR(X,1+(LEVEL-1)*5,5)
---------- --------------------------------
         1 AAAAA
         2 BBBBB
         3 CCCCC
         4 DDDDD
```

Now you need a way to concatenate all these substrings, adding `'E'` and `'F'`; here I use `sys_connect_by_path` by concatenating the `'F'` at the end and using the `'E'` as separator:

```
SQL> select level, sys_connect_by_path( substr(x, 1 + (level-1)*5, 5) || 'F', 'E') result
  2    FROM (select 'AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD' x from dual) text
  3  CONNECT BY level * 5 <= length(x);

     LEVEL RESULT
---------- ------------------------------
         1 EAAAAAF
         2 EAAAAAFEBBBBBF
         3 EAAAAAFEBBBBBFECCCCCF
         4 EAAAAAFEBBBBBFECCCCCFEDDDDDF
```

Last step, you just need the "last" row, that is the leaf of the tree generated by recursion, so you add

```
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
```

To handle the case in which the latest group of characters is less than 5, you can edit the `CONNECT BY` clause into:

```
CONNECT BY (level-1) * 5 < length(x);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks alot. let say after 5 letter blocks are over there is remaining 3 letters remaining(less than 5 at the end) at the  end how can I modify your query to append F and E to that remaining block? I Mean something like AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDDGGGG=>EAAAAAFEBBBBDFECCCCCFEDDDDDFEGGGGF(only 3 Gs)

Comment: Thanks alot.In Case I have a line break at the middle is it possible to append  E and F to line break part? I mean AAAAA<br>BBBBBCCCCCDDDDDGGGG=> EAAAAAFEFEBBBBDFECCCCCFEDDDDDFEGGGGF